# Trouble setting up visualvm on Mac Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, visualvm

I'm using Eclipse Juno on Mac 10.9.1.  I just downloaded the VisualVM (137) app and installed the corresponding Eclipse plugin.  However, I'm having a problem configuring the Eclipse pluign. When I go to Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching -> VisualVM Configuration, I enter

```
/Applications/VisualVM.app
```

as the path to the VisualVm Executable.  However, I get this error message

```
Invalid VisualVM installation location.  Make s…file selected exists and is indeed a VisualVM
```

and I'm unable to save my configuration.  I've verified the path above exists.  What path should I be entering for my Visual VM executable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `/Applications/VisualVM.app/Contents/MacOS/visualvm` as the path to the VisualVM executable.